# Number of solutions of $x_1+2x_2+\cdots+kx_k=n$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, diophantine-equations, generating-functions, linear-diophantine-equations

Suppose $n$ be a given positive integer. Then the Diophantine equation $x=n$ has only $1$ solution. Just by inspection, I found that the Diophantine equation $x+2y=n$ has $\left\lfloor \dfrac{n}{2}+1\right\rfloor$ non-negative solutions for $(x,y).$
Also, according to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452100/the-solutions-of-x2y3z-n-x-y-z-in-mathbb-n) the Diophantine equation $x+2y+3z=n$ has $\left\lfloor \dfrac{n^2}{12}+\dfrac{n}{2}+1 \right\rfloor$ non-negative solutions for $(x,y).$

> Is there any closed form for the number of non-negative integer solutions for $(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_k)$ of $$x_1+2x_2+3x_3+\cdots+kx_k=n$$ for a given $k\in\Bbb{N}$?
>
> How can I prove these formulas rigorously?

**EDIT**
After a very tedious calculation I found that the equation $w+2x+3y+4z=n$ has  $\left\lfloor \dfrac{n^3}{144}+\dfrac{5n^2}{48}+\dfrac{(15+(-1)^n)n}{32}+1 \right\rfloor$ solutions.
This solution completely agree with the approximation given by **Rus May**.
However still I believe that we can do something more than this.

Comment: You are asking for the number of partitions of $n$ into parts of sizes $\leq k$. Don't think there is a closed formula holding for all $n, k$. But for each fixed $k$, the number can be computed as the $t^n$-coefficient of the formal power series $\dfrac{1}{\left(1-t\right)\left(1-t^2\right) \cdots\left(1-t^k\right)}$, which should fall prey to some standard methods (it satisfies a linear recurrence, if I remember correctly?).

Comment: It can be proved that the multinomial of $x_i$, $1\leq i \leq k$ is equal the $n$th term of generalized Fibonacci numbers, as shown
$$
\sum_{(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_k)} 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_1+\cdots+x_k \\
x_1,\cdots , x_k
\end{array}
\right)=f_n\, .
$$
where the summation is over non-negative integers satisfying
$$
x_1+2\, x_2+3\, x_3+\cdots + k\, x_k=n \, .
$$

and  $f_n$ is the generalized Fibonacci numbers, as follows 
$$
f_n=\sum_{i=1}^k f_{n-i} \quad , \quad (f_0,\cdots,f_{k-2},f_{k-1})=(0,\cdots,0,1) \, .
$$

Comment: References are [*generalized Fibonacci sequence*](http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/22-3/er.pdf) and [*Combinatorial method*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379595901639).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Darij Grinberg says, there's not a nice closed formula for this. There is, however, a really neat approximation via [Schur's theorem in combinatorics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur's_theorem#Combinatorics). It goes like this.

The singularities of the generating function $\frac1{(1-t)(1-t^2)\cdots(1-t^k)}$ all lie on the unit circle in the complex plane. The partial fractions decomposition of the generating function has terms of the form $\frac\alpha{(1-x/\omega)^{1+\ell}}$, where $\alpha$ is a constant, $\omega$ is a root of unity, and $\ell$ is a natural number less than $k$. The coefficient of such a term is $\alpha\binom{n+\ell}{\ell}/\omega^\ell$, so the term with the highest multiplicity makes the greatest contribution. In this case, it is the singularity at 1 with $\ell=k-1$. Then the coefficient of $t^n$ in the generating function is approximately
\begin{eqnarray*}
[t^n]\frac1{(1-t)\cdots(1-t^k)}&=&\alpha\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}+o(n^{k-1})\\
&=&\alpha\frac{n^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}+o(n^{k-1}).
\end{eqnarray*}
To evaluate the constant $\alpha$, just multiply the generating function and the partial fractions decomposition by $(1-t)^k$ and take the limit at 1, resulting in $\alpha=1/k!$. Then, Schur's approximation to the number of solutions of $x_1+2x_2+\cdots+kx_k=n$ is
$$\frac{n^{k-1}}{(k-1)!\,k!} .$$

Comment: Is there any relationship between this equation and the partition function? If there any such relation, could you please explain it?

Comment: If by "partition function" you mean [partitions of integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)), then your problem is a finite version of partitions of integers. The generating function that marks the number of partitions of an integer would be  $\frac{1}{(1-t)(1-t^2)(1-t^3)\cdots}$.

Comment: If we substitute $x_k=y_1$, $x_k+x_{k-1}=y_2$ and finally $x_k+\cdots+x_2+x_1=y_k,$ then $n=y_1+y_2+\cdots+y_k,$ where $0\le y_1\le y_2\le \cdots\le y_k.$ Therefore actually we need is number of ways that $n$ can written as sum of $k$ non-negative integers without considering the order. Am I correct? Is there any way to do this without using generating functions?

Answer (score 0):

Read my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3240121/whats-the-number-of-natural-solutions-of-x-1-2x-2-3x-3-n/4426784#4426784); the number of partitions of $n$ with largest part $k$ is the same as the number of partitions into $k$ parts, which is $p(n,k)$. Using this, the number of solutions of the equation $\sum i x_{i} = n$ is equal to :

$$p(n, 1) + p(n, 2) + \cdots + p(n, k).$$