# Asymptotic of inverse q-Pochhammer symbol

Tags: asymptotics, pochhammer-symbol

Let $(x,q)_k$ denote the $q$-Pochhammer symbol and $\mathrm{Coeff}_n\hspace{0.1em} f(q)$ denote the coefficient of $q^n$ in $f(q)$.
What I want to know is the large-$n$ asymptotic of
\begin{align}
     \mathrm{Coeff}_n\hspace{0.1em} \frac{1}{(q;q)_k}
     \,,
\end{align}
and also
\begin{align}
     \mathrm{Coeff}_n\hspace{0.1em} \frac{1}{(q;q)_\infty}
     =\mathrm{Coeff}_n\hspace{0.1em}
     \bigg(
            1 + q + 2q^2 + 3q^3 + 5q^4 + 7q^5 + 11q^6 + 15q^7 + \cdots
     \bigg)
     \,.
\end{align}
How can I find these? I tried to use Mathematica, like this,
\begin{align}
    &
    \texttt{DiscreteAsymptotic}\Big[
    \texttt{SeriesCoefficient}\big[
          1/\texttt{QPochhammer}[q,q,k],
          \{q,0,n\}
    \big],
    n{\to}\infty
    \Big]
    \,,\\
    &
    \texttt{DiscreteAsymptotic}\Big[
    \texttt{SeriesCoefficient}\big[
          1/\texttt{QPochhammer}[q,q],
          \{q,0,n\}
    \big],
    n{\to}\infty
    \Big]
    \,,
\end{align}
but unfortunately it returned nothing.
I would appreciate any help or suggestions.

One of my attempts was to use somehow the following $q$-binomial expression,
\begin{align}
        \frac{1}{(x;q)_N} 
        = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{N+k-1}{k}_{\hspace{-0.15em} q} x^k
        \,,
\end{align}
but I am not sure whether if plugging in $q$ to $x$ results in anything useful...

Comment: Ramanujan and Hardy showed the asymptotic formula $$
\text{Coeff}_n \frac{1}{{(q;q)_\infty  }} = p(n) \sim \frac{1}{{4n\sqrt 3 }}\exp \left( {\pi\sqrt {\frac{2n}{3}} } \right).
$$ Here $p(n)$ is the partition function. An exact formula with asymptotic character was given by Rademacher. For more details, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)#Approximation_formulas).

Comment: Interesting! Thank you very much. For finite $N$, I think [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2055580/577622) may provide an answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Too long for a comment.*

For the asymptotic, @Gary already gave the answer in comments.

Looking at sequence [$A000041$](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+5%2C+7%2C+11%2C+15%2C+22%2C+30%2C+42%2C+56%2C+77%2C+101%2C+135%2C+176&language=english&go=Search) in $OEIS$, you would find a very good approximation proposed in year $2016$ by Vaclav Kotesovec. It can rewrite
$$a_n=\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{3} n}\,\exp\Bigg[\,\pi \sqrt{\frac{2 n}{3}\Bigg[1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac {a_i}{n^{\frac {k+1}2} }\Bigg] }\,\,\, \Bigg]$$ the first coefficients being

$$a_1=\frac{\pi ^2-18}{4 \sqrt{6} \pi ^3}\qquad a_2=\frac{3}{4 \pi ^4}\qquad a_3=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\,\frac{36-5 \pi ^2}{32 \pi ^5}\qquad  a_4 =\frac{3348-120 \pi ^2+5 \pi ^4}{1920 \pi ^6}$$

For $n=10^3$, the relative error is $1.31$%