# Name of such combinatorial numbers.

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, terminology, integer-partitions

Let $k,n\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $N(k,n)$ denote the size of the finite set
$$\{(x_1,\cdots,x_k)\in\mathbb{N}^k:x_1+2x_2+\cdots+kx_k=n\}. $$

I feel it special and important. Do $N(k,n)$ have names? Is there a table of values?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2053319/number-of-solutions-of-x-12x-2-cdotskx-k-n?rq=1

Comment: As for a name and easy closed form, neither exist to my knowledge.  Approximations exist, read the linked post for one such method to approximate.

Comment: This is the number of partitions of $n-k$ into parts up to $k$.

Comment: While not a name, it's certainly related to [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faà_di_Bruno's_formula).

Comment: $N(k,n)$ is in bijection with the set of integer partitions of $n$ where every part has size at most $k$. In this correspondence, $x_i$ represents the number of parts with size $i$. It is also in bijection with partitions of $n$ with at most $k$ parts (via conjugation). Therefore, your question is a duplicate of this one: [Number of ways to write $n$ as a sum of $k$ nonnegative integers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217597/number-of-ways-to-write-n-as-a-sum-of-k-nonnegative-integers)